# JS detect rendered fonts vs computed styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm using this JS script, found on [github](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/macbookandrew/f33dbbc0aa582d0515919dc5fb95c00a/raw/fd60a5ba2de87410d325dbb9293af8122122ae1f/findStyles.js), to detect fonts used in webpages:

```
function styleInPage(css, verbose) {
    // polyfill getComputedStyle
    if (typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined") {
        getComputedStyle = function (elem) {
            return elem.currentStyle;
        }
    }

    // set vars
    var style,
        thisNode,
        styleId,
        allStyles = [],
        nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

    // loop over all elements
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        thisNode = nodes[i];
        if (thisNode.style) {
            styleId = '#' + (thisNode.id || thisNode.nodeName + '(' + i + ')');
            style = thisNode.style.fontFamily || getComputedStyle(thisNode, '')[css];

            // get element’s style
            if (style) {
                if (verbose) {
                    allStyles.push([styleId, style]);
                } else if (allStyles.indexOf(style) == -1) {
                    allStyles.push(style);
                }

                // add data-attribute with key for allStyles array
                thisNode.dataset.styleId = allStyles.indexOf(style);
            }

            // get element:before’s style
            styleBefore = getComputedStyle(thisNode, ':before')[css];
            if (styleBefore) {
                if (verbose) {
                    allStyles.push([styleId, styleBefore]);
                } else if (allStyles.indexOf(styleBefore) == -1) {
                    allStyles.push(styleBefore);
                }

                // add data-attribute with key for allStyles array
                thisNode.dataset.styleId = allStyles.indexOf(styleBefore);
            }

            // get element:after’s style
            styleAfter = getComputedStyle(thisNode, ':after')[css];
            if (styleAfter) {
                if (verbose) {
                    allStyles.push([styleId, styleAfter]);
                } else if (allStyles.indexOf(styleAfter) == -1) {
                    allStyles.push(styleAfter);
                }

                // add data-attribute with key for allStyles array
                thisNode.dataset.styleId = allStyles.indexOf(styleAfter);
            }
        }
    }
    return allStyles;
}
```

Thing is if I use the `getComputedStyle` I do get the style, say if i look for font-family, but I don't get the exact name of the rendered font. Whereas if I check the DevTools in Chrome, I can see the actual name of the exact typeface.

eg. if you use this script against websites like https://carpentercollective.com/
I get the font used is `serif1` but the rendered font is actually called `Grifo`

[image]
[image]

How to I get that info with JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the CSS rules in document.styleSheets, you will find these:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'serif1';
    src: url("https://carpentercollective.com/wp-content/themes/carpentercollective/assets/fonts/Grifo M Medium.woff") format("woff"),url("https://carpentercollective.com/wp-content/themes/carpentercollective/assets/fonts/Grifo M Medium.eot") format("eot")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'serif2';
    src: url("https://carpentercollective.com/wp-content/themes/carpentercollective/assets/fonts/Grifo M Regular.woff") format("woff"),url("https://carpentercollective.com/wp-content/themes/carpentercollective/assets/fonts/Grifo M Regular.eot") format("eot")
}
```

This is a step closer to find the real name of the font, and for that I believe you will have to XHR the file and parse the name of it... I guess there are libraries already that read the metadata of fonts available.

This would only work for web fonts, if the family name is "sans-serif", for example, I don't think you will be able to figure out the font the browser is replacing it with from the computer installed fonts. Well, at least not easily or in all cases. There are some experiments that measure different characters of fonts and then compare against a known database of popular fonts, and it could be possible to do it by rendering in a canvas and comparing pixel values to be more precise... but in any case just hacks, never the browser telling you what is installed in the computer.

Comment: it seems chrome uses the same font name minus the extension...maybe that's the right way... I'll try it

Comment: and yes, I'm not expecting to know the generic serif/sans-serif... thanks